# preventing a Smarty 2 template from being cached/compiled

Tags: php, caching, smarty, template-engine, smarty2

I have an issue with Smarty 2.6.9 caching, where I have a 2 templates called `confirmation.tpl` which are both stored in different directories in my codebase.

However, when they are compiled they are compiled in a `/cache/gb/` directory. For these two templates only I would like to prevent the compiling, and as such I have attempted to use the `force_compile` member variable, however this is having no effect at all and the template is consistently cached.

The problem that this is presenting is that both `confirmation.tpl` templates are being called (by separate code) on the *same* page, so one template is being used for both and is causing me problems.

Is there a way that I can prevent this template from being compiled and cached in this way?

I am passing a flag through to set "no_compile" for the "confirmation.tpl" template ONLY.

```
    $this->obj = new Smarty;
    $this->obj->caching = false;
    $this->obj->cache_lifetime = 10; 
    $this->obj->compile_check = true;
    $this->obj->template_dir = $this->tpl_path;

    if ($this->no_compile) {
        $this->obj->force_compile = false;
        $this->obj->compile_check = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use different `$compile_id` settings in display/fetch to get different physical files on disk (although I think Smarty should handle this automagically for you depending on the path). `compile_id` can also be set for `{include}` statements.

I'm not sure what the code you've pasted implies, but you will want to turn on `force_compile` to make Smarty regenerate the template each time it is shown (it's `false` by default).

Comment: I think I may be barking up the wrong tree then. My problem is that when I clear the compile directory of all `confirmation.tpl.php` files and refresh the page the file returns, _but only one file returns_ whereas I believe there should be two (as there are two `confirmation.tpl` Smarty templates called on the page).

Comment: For those looking for this in future, this is what I done: `// $this->obj is an instance of the Smarty class
$compile_id = md5(__METHOD__);
$output = $this->obj->fetch($top_tpl_file, null, $compile_id, $display);`